# MySQL database model for signups with and without addresses

Tags: mysql, registration, modeling

I've been thinking about this all evening (GMT) but I can't seem to figure out a good solution for this one. Here's the case...

I have to create a signup system which distinguishes 4 kinds of "users":

- Individual sign ups (require address info)
- Group sign ups (don't require address info)
- Group contact (require address info)
- Application users (don't require address info)

I really cannot come up with a decent way of modeling this into something that makes sense. I'd greatly appreciate it if you could share your ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go with a construction where group members are separated from the user pool anyway. The group members eventually have no relation with a user since they don't require access to mutating their personal data, that's what a group contact person is for. Eventually I could add a possibility for groups to have multiple contact persons, even distinguishing persons that are or are not allowed to edit any member data.

That's my answer on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like good case for single table inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Requiring certain data is more a function of your application logic than your database.  You can definitely define database columns that don't allow NULL values, but they can be set to "" (empty string) without any errors.

As far as how to structure your database, have two separate tables:

- User
- UserAddress

When you have a new signup that requires contact info, your application will create records in both tables.  When a new signup doesn't require address info, your application will only create a record in the User table.

Comment: The idea behind not allowing NULL as much as possible is to prevent gaps from forming in the database files on the disk, making the files unnecessarily large. Is this a misconception?

Comment: I've not heard this before, but if you can provide a reference, I would be glad to read it.

Comment: I'll just discard that idea since all the proof I have is a feint memory of reading it somewhere.

Comment: Yes, nulls are not avoided to prevent gaps in the disk. That is a misconception.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple considerations here: first, I like to look at User/Group as a case of a Composite pattern. It clearly meets the requirement: you often have to treat the aggregate and individual versions of the entity interchangeably (as you note). Implementing a composite in a database is not that hard. If you are using an ORM, it is pretty simple (inheritance).

On the other part of the question, you always have the ability to create data structures that are mostly empty. Generally, that's a bad idea. So you can say 'well, in the beginning, we don't have any information about the User so we will just leave all the other fields blank.' A better approach is to try and model the phases as if they were part of an FSM. One of the clearest ways to do this in this particular case is to distinguish between Users, Accounts and some other more domain-specific entity, e.g. Subscriber or Customer. Then, I can come and browse using User, sign up and make an Account, then later when you want address and other personal information, become a subscriber. This would also imply inheritance, and you have the added benefit of being able to have a true representation of the population at any time that doesn't require stupid shenanigans like 'SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE **_** not null,' etc.

Comment: I think the keyword for me in this is inheritance (also mentioned @Kelend). I think also considering the technical design I have in mind for the application, this would in fact make the most sense. Could you perhaps give an example of how I can model database entities in FSM perspective?

Comment: In the example I gave, I am saying that the state machine is moving people from being casual lurkers (Users) to being registered (having an Account) to being active members (Member, Subscriber, Customer, whatever). That's the state machine: the person progresses through various states rather than just making a big blob of sparse data that haphazardly gets filled in over time.

Comment: In my case I don't think the FSM would work because as soon as an entry is made, the entry is either one of the different types of users. They do not change over time.

Comment: Then just use the inheritance and the types are all differentiated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion from my end after weighing pro's and con's on this model. As I think the ideal setup is to have all users be a user entity that belong to a group without differentiating groups from individuals (except of course flag a group contact person and creating a link with a groups table) we came up with the alternative to copy the group contact user details to the group members when they group is created.

This way all entities that actually *are* a person will get their own table.

Could this be a good idea? Awaiting your comments :)